# this.Teams = new ObservableCollection<TeamViewModel>(_teams);

Tags: silverlight, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm new to mvvm and I can't seem to find the answer to the following:

I have a datagrid in Silverlight which binds to a observablecollection Teams of a viewmodel:
First I fetch a couple of team objects in a List and then I feed them to my observablecollection
(Public ObservableCollection Teams)

Now I want to add a row in the Datagrid so I created a button in the view and hooked up an Icommand which adds more or less an empty team to my collection:

```
private void Add()
    {

                    Team _team = new Team();

                    _team.recid = 1;
                    _team.teamid = "";
                    _team.ruleset = "";
                    _team.name = "";
                    this.Teams.Add(new TeamViewModel(_team));
    }
```

I think the notifypropertychanged doesn't fire (only when I set the collection), what do I have to do to notify the view of my changed viewmodel?

Thanks in advance,

Michael

Answer (score 0):

Adding to an ObservableCollection does not raise PropertyChanged, but instead raises a collectionchanged event.

The easiest way is to manually RaisePropertyChanged for the Team property at the end of your add function.

Answer (score 0):

If you databound your Teams property (which is of the type ObservableCollection), your Grid should automatically update.

There's no reason to call RaisePropertyChanged("Teams") when adding or removing items from a ObservableCollection.

So in short, it should already work. If it doesn't, you need to post more code.

Comment: thanks for replying!
It doesn't work yet, raising manually doesn't do it either so I suspect I'm not binding correctly.
Here's some code from the xaml (in the usercontrol):
DataContext="{Binding Main, Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource Locator}}

<data:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Teams}"  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTeam, Mode=TwoWay}"

Main is the MainTeamViewModel property in my ViewModelLocator
Teams is the observabe collection

Comment: It could be related to your UserControl, or the DataGrid you're using.  Also, if you're using Silverlight 4, you could just use the default DataGrid  ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid(v=vs.95).aspx ).

Comment: I guess it didn't show up in the grid because I added empty strings for teamid / name.
When I do it like this the row is visible in the grid:
         _team.recid = 1;
         _team.teamid = "test";
         _team.ruleset = "test";
         _team.name = "test";
         _team.rowstate = GlobalVariables.Rowstate.added;

Thanks Claus / Brandorf for your comments!

Regards,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

I guess it didn't show up in the grid because I added empty strings for teamid / name. When I do it like this the row is visible in the grid: _team.recid = 1; _team.teamid = "test"; _team.ruleset = "test"; _team.name = "test"; _team.rowstate = GlobalVariables.Rowstate.added; Thanks Claus / Brandorf for your comments! 
Regards, Mike

Comment: Usualy writing an answer to a question you posted yourself is considered bad practice. Better edit your post and accept/up vote the answers that helped you or solved your problem.